# scipy.optimize.linprog unable to find a feasible starting point despite a feasible answer clearly exists

Tags: python, scipy, linear-programming

the vector k seems to satisfy all constraints. Is there something I'm missing here? Thanks.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import linprog
A_ub=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 1, -1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, -1, 1]]
b_ub=[ 10000.,    100.,  10000.,   1840.,  10000.,   4000.,  10000.,
      100.,  10000.,   5000.,  10000.,   5450.,  10000.,   3000.,
    10000.,   3000.,  10000.,   1000.,  40000.,   5000.,   5000.]
A_eq=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0.0, -5000.0, 13390.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1840.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0.0, 5000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [13290.0, 0.0, -13390.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -5450.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 1, -1], [-13290.0, 5000.0, 0.0, 1840.0, 5450.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1]]
b_eq=[8390.0, 0, -1840.0, 0, 5000.0, 0, -100.0, 0, 0.0, 0, -5450.0, 0, 0.0, 0, 0.0, 0, -1000.0, 0]
c=[-1351.6146468256165, -99.629272305631787, -542.0389808700279, -0.0, 54.302887927385768, -0.043903442258601377, -0.10170162880553937, -0.043903442258601377, -0.043903442258601377, -0.043903442258601377, -0.11764394156352764, -0.043903442258601377, -0.056182133775492554, -0.043903442258601377, -0.043903442258601377, -0.033174575907634424, -0.081074546005202835, -0.043903442258601377, -0.057503980336247616, -0.040480879825992883, -0.046889515046147204, -0.10170162880553937, 0.02, 0.02, 0, 0, 0.02, 0.02, 0, 0, 0.02, 0.02, 0, 0, 0.02, 0.02, 0, 0, 0.02, 0.02, 0, 0, 0.02, 0.02, 0, 0, 0.02, 0.02, 0, 0, 0.02, 0.02, 0, 0, 0.02, 0.02, 0, 0]
k=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8390.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1840.0, 0, 0, 5000.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100.0, 0, 0, 0.0, 0.0, 0, 0, 0, 5450.0, 0, 0, 0.0, 0.0, 0, 0, 0.0, 0.0, 0, 0, 0, 1000.0]

print(all(np.dot(A_ub, k)<=b_ub))
print(all(np.dot(A_eq, k)==b_eq))
print(all(map(lambda x :x>=0, k)))
linprog(c, A_ub, b_ub, A_eq, b_eq)
```

Answer (score 8):

This answer doesn't explain *why* it works.  I hope someone more familiar with the `linprog` code or with linear programming in general can give a more thorough answer.

---

I get a solution if I use the option `bland=True` (see [`show_options`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.show_options.html) for documentation--scroll to the bottom for the `linprog` options):

```
In [130]: linprog(c, A_ub, b_ub, A_eq, b_eq, options=dict(bland=True))
Out[130]: 
  status: 0
   slack: array([  3610.,   6490.,  11840.,      0.,      0.,  14000.,  10100.,
            0.,  10000.,   5000.,  15450.,      0.,  13000.,      0.,
        10000.,   3000.,  11000.,      0.,  12220.,      0.,  10000.])
 success: True
     fun: -2683.6935269049131
       x: array([  1.22573363e+00,   2.00000000e+00,   1.22404780e+00,
         3.71739130e+00,   8.25688073e-02,   2.00000000e+03,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         5.00000000e+03,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   2.00000000e+03,
         6.39000000e+03,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   1.84000000e+03,
         5.00000000e+03,   0.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+04,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+02,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  -1.11022302e-12,   0.00000000e+00,
         5.45000000e+03,   0.00000000e+00,   3.00000000e+03,
         0.00000000e+00,   3.00000000e+03,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         1.00000000e+03])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     nit: 50
```

One component is slightly negative (-1.11e-12).  Presumably this is within the default tolerance.  That can be cleaned up by lowering the tolerance (but note the change in `x[19]`):

```
In [131]: linprog(c, A_ub, b_ub, A_eq, b_eq, options=dict(bland=True, tol=1e-15))
Out[131]: 
  status: 0
   slack: array([  3610.,   6490.,  11840.,      0.,      0.,  14000.,  10100.,
            0.,  10000.,   5000.,  15450.,      0.,  13000.,      0.,
        10000.,   3000.,  11000.,      0.,  12220.,      0.,  10000.])
 success: True
     fun: -2683.693526904935
       x: array([  1.22573363e+00,   2.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         3.71739130e+00,   8.25688073e-02,   2.00000000e+03,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         5.00000000e+03,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   1.63900000e+04,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   2.00000000e+03,
         6.39000000e+03,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   1.84000000e+03,
         5.00000000e+03,   0.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+04,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+02,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         5.45000000e+03,   0.00000000e+00,   3.00000000e+03,
         0.00000000e+00,   3.00000000e+03,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         1.00000000e+03])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     nit: 51
```

Comment: Thank you. Upvoted, but not yet accepted so we can both wait to see if someone better acquainted with the algorithm/code can explain why.

Comment: it seems that the bland=True in unnecessary. just linprog(c, A_ub, b_ub, A_eq, b_eq, options=dict(tol=1e-8)) is enough

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a tolerance issue.

I was able to "fix" it by importing the [original linprog code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/optimize/_linprog.py#L825), after  I changed the tolerance (`tol` parameter) from `10e-12` to `10e-8` in the "private" method `_linprog_simplex`.

This parameter is passed to the method `_pivot_col`, which reads

```
ma = np.ma.masked_where(T[-1, :-1] >= -tol, T[-1, :-1], copy=False)
    if ma.count() == 0:
        return False, np.nan
    if bland:
        return True, np.where(ma.mask == False)[0][0]
    return True, np.ma.where(ma == ma.min())[0][0]
```

This is why `bland`'s rule passes the test, while the default one fails. I then tried to find if there is any default tolerance in the implementation of [`numpy.masked_where`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/ma/core.py#L1701). From there, it is not obvious what is the tolerance that is used, but other numpy functions, such as [masked_values](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/ma/core.py#L2123), have an absolute tolerance of `10e-8` by default.

I hope this helps.

Here is the result I am getting by changing the tolerance in `_linprog_simplex`:

```
True
True
True
  status: 0
   slack: array([  3610.,   6490.,  11840.,      0.,      0.,  14000.,  10100.,
            0.,  10000.,   5000.,  15450.,      0.,  13000.,      0.,
        10000.,   3000.,  11000.,      0.,  12220.,      0.,  10000.])
 success: True
     fun: -2683.6935269049141
       x: array([  1.22573363e+00,   2.00000000e+00,   1.22404780e+00,
         3.71739130e+00,   8.25688073e-02,   2.00000000e+03,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         5.00000000e+03,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   2.00000000e+03,
         6.39000000e+03,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   1.84000000e+03,
         5.00000000e+03,   0.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+04,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+02,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         5.45000000e+03,   0.00000000e+00,   3.00000000e+03,
         0.00000000e+00,   3.00000000e+03,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         1.00000000e+03])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     nit: 26
```

PS: I also had to change the line

```
from .optimize import OptimizeResult, _check_unknown_options
```

to

```
from scipy.optimize import OptimizeResult
```

and remove the call to `_check_unknown_options` in line 533 of the original code.